# How to see which lock was set in transaction sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, multithreading, locking

I want to demo the lost update problem which this example

```
Create table tblInventory
(
    Id int,
    Name varchar(50),
    ItemsInStock int
    Constraint PK_PRODUCT
    Primary key (Id)
)
Insert tblInventory
Values (1,'Iphone',10)
```

```
 -- Transaction 1
 Begin Tran
 Declare @ItemsInStock int

 Select @ItemsInStock = ItemsInStock
 from tblInventory where Id=1

 -- Transaction takes 10 seconds

 Waitfor Delay '00:00:10'
 Set @ItemsInStock = @ItemsInStock - 1

 Update tblInventory
 Set ItemsInStock = @ItemsInStock where Id=1

 Print @ItemsInStock

 Commit Transaction


 -- Transaction 2
 Begin Tran
 Declare @ItemsInStock int

 Select @ItemsInStock = ItemsInStock
 from tblInventory where Id=1

 -- Transaction takes 1 second
 Waitfor Delay '00:00:1'
 Set @ItemsInStock = @ItemsInStock - 2

 Update tblInventory
 Set ItemsInStock = @ItemsInStock where Id=1

 Print @ItemsInStock

 Commit Transaction
```

This example I get from this link: http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2015/08/sql-server-lost-update-problem.html

This example will corrupt lost update and I want to ask that have anyway to show which lock was set in transaction 1 and 2 on SQL Server like this:

Select => Lock type: S (Shared lock) => Isolation level : Read Committed

Update => Lock type: X (Exclusive lock) => Isolation level : Read Committed

As I know that when Select we will get Shared lock and when Update we will get Exclusive lock but I want display this in SQL Server

I have try use sp_who and sp_lock but not display the result I want

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

PS:/I have a small question that how to know which transaction can get lost update problem by look the query ?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create an Extended Event trace including the lock_acquired and lock_released events. Add a filter to trace only those sessions of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Extended Event trace including the lock_acquired and lock_released events. Add a filter to trace only those sessions of interest.

Below is trace example DDL for a session that writes events to a trace file for 2 sessions filtered on session_id. The trace can be started, stopped, and viewed from SSMS (Management-->Extended Events-->Sessions.

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [locks] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.lock_acquired(SET collect_resource_description=(1)
    ACTION(sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.sql_text)
    WHERE ([sqlserver].[session_id]=(56) OR [sqlserver].[session_id]=(57))),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.lock_released(SET collect_resource_description=(1)
    ACTION(sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.sql_text)
    WHERE ([sqlserver].[session_id]=(56) OR [sqlserver].[session_id]=(57)))
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'locks')
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=1048576 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=OFF)
GO
```